# Cron last execution to be at 7 p.m

Tags: cron

I wrote a quartz2 cron to execute every 15 min between 7 a.m. to 7 p.m. Mon to Fri

My concern is that last execution is at 6:45 p.m. rather than 7 p.m.

MY Cron : **0+0/15+07-18+?+*+MON-FRI+***

Could someone please help how to make **last execution at 7 p.m.** and then stop?

Comment: Can you schedule a second job that runs at 7pm? That seems like the simplest way.

Comment: For now I have changed the seconds to 2 seconds instead of 0. Hope its working. 2+0/15+07-18+?++MON-FRI+

Comment: @Jon The 2 seconds things didn't worked. Wrote a separate job that runs at 7 p.m. :-(